# Exported same file in Gerber X2 and ODB++ and diffrent result

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers, gerber

Using Altium I exported ***the same*** PCB in Gerber X2 and ODB++ and sent it to production (so they could choose what file format they preferred).
The manufacturer came back asking why the design did not look the same in Gerber and ODB++.

I reexported and it still looks different when comparing the same layer (see images. Only one layer showed in both photos).
What is shown in the images attached are some vias and some holes for a pogo pin programmer connector.

Does anyone know why this is happening? any setting that is wrong or why would the holes be filled in the Gerber?
I have checked but have not found any setting that helps.

[image: ODB]
[image: Gerber]

Comment: What version of Altium? I assume those are supposed to be plane clearance areas.

Comment: Altium designer. Version 22.3.1 (build 43)

Comment: Yes, this is an internal layer with some vias, a track, and some holes for a connector. outside these objects, there is a polygon.